# How to get the uri of a clicked image on gridview?

Tags: android, image, gridview, uri

I have an activity called GalleryActivity.java that loads the images of a selected folder into a gridview using the class GridViewAdapter.java. When a image on this gridview is clicked, I want to get its uri and pass it to another activity. But I can't figure out how to get the uri of clicked image.

Here is the code for GalleryActivity.java:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class GalleryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static ArrayList<Model_images> al_images = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean boolean_folder;
    Adapter_PhotosFolder obj_adapter;
    GridView folder_gridview, gridView;
    GridViewAdapter adapter;
    ImageButton btnBack;
    private int folder_gridview_slideout_position = 190;
    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS = 100;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery);

        folder_gridview = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gallery_gridview_folders);
        gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gallery_gridview_photos);


        // when gridview folder is clicked
        folder_gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int int_position, long l) {

                //load photos into gridview
                adapter = new GridViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(),al_images,int_position);
                gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
        });

        // when a photo on gridView is clicked
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
           // Here is the part where I want to get uri of image
            }
        });


        if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            if ((ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(GalleryActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) && (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(GalleryActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))) {

            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(GalleryActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);
            }
        }else {
            Log.e("Else","Else");
            fn_imagespath();
        }

    }


    // returns an array of images
    public ArrayList<Model_images> fn_imagespath() {
        al_images.clear();

        int int_position = 0;
        Uri uri;
        Cursor cursor;
        int column_index_data, column_index_folder_name;

        String absolutePathOfImage = null;
        uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME};

        final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN;
        cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, orderBy + " DESC");

        column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
        column_index_folder_name = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            absolutePathOfImage = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
            Log.e("Column", absolutePathOfImage);
            Log.e("Folder", cursor.getString(column_index_folder_name));

            for (int i = 0; i < al_images.size(); i++) {
                if (al_images.get(i).getStr_folder().equals(cursor.getString(column_index_folder_name))) {
                    boolean_folder = true;
                    int_position = i;
                    break;
                } else {
                    boolean_folder = false;
                }
            }


            if (boolean_folder) {

                ArrayList<String> al_path = new ArrayList<>();
                al_path.addAll(al_images.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath());
                al_path.add(absolutePathOfImage);
                al_images.get(int_position).setAl_imagepath(al_path);

            } else {
                ArrayList<String> al_path = new ArrayList<>();
                al_path.add(absolutePathOfImage);
                Model_images obj_model = new Model_images();
                obj_model.setStr_folder(cursor.getString(column_index_folder_name));
                obj_model.setAl_imagepath(al_path);

                al_images.add(obj_model);


            }


        }


        for (int i = 0; i < al_images.size(); i++) {
            Log.e("FOLDER", al_images.get(i).getStr_folder());
            for (int j = 0; j < al_images.get(i).getAl_imagepath().size(); j++) {
                Log.e("FILE", al_images.get(i).getAl_imagepath().get(j));
            }
        }
        obj_adapter = new Adapter_PhotosFolder(getApplicationContext(),al_images);
        folder_gridview.setAdapter(obj_adapter);
        return al_images;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_PERMISSIONS: {
                for (int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++) {
                    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        fn_imagespath();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(GalleryActivity.this, "The app was not allowed to read or write to your storage. Please consider granting it this permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And here is the code for GridViewAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class GridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model_images> {

    Context context;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    ArrayList<Model_images> al_menu = new ArrayList<>();
    int int_position;


    public GridViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Model_images> al_menu, int int_position) {
        super(context, R.layout.adapter_photosfolder, al_menu);
        this.al_menu = al_menu;
        this.context = context;
        this.int_position = int_position;


    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        Log.e("ADAPTER LIST SIZE", al_menu.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().size() + "");
        return al_menu.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        if (al_menu.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().size() > 0) {
            return al_menu.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().size();
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_photosfolder, parent, false);
            viewHolder.tv_foldern = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_folder);
            viewHolder.tv_foldersize = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_folder2);
            viewHolder.iv_image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_image);


            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.tv_foldern.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        viewHolder.tv_foldersize.setVisibility(View.GONE);



        Glide.with(context).load("file://" + al_menu.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().get(position))
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                .skipMemoryCache(true)
                .into(viewHolder.iv_image);


        return convertView;

    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tv_foldern, tv_foldersize;
        ImageView iv_image;


    }


}
```

Here is the Model_images.java class

```
public class Model_images {
String str_folder;
ArrayList<String> al_imagepath;

public String getStr_folder() {
    return str_folder;
}

public void setStr_folder(String str_folder) {
    this.str_folder = str_folder;
}

public ArrayList<String> getAl_imagepath() {
    return al_imagepath;
}

public void setAl_imagepath(ArrayList<String> al_imagepath) {
    this.al_imagepath = al_imagepath;
}
}
```

Here is the Adapter_PhotosFolder.java class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Adapter_PhotosFolder extends ArrayAdapter<Model_images> {

    Context context;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    ArrayList<Model_images> al_menu = new ArrayList<>();


    public Adapter_PhotosFolder(Context context, ArrayList<Model_images> al_menu) {
        super(context, R.layout.adapter_photosfolder, al_menu);
        this.al_menu = al_menu;
        this.context = context;


    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        Log.e("ADAPTER LIST SIZE", al_menu.size() + "");
        return al_menu.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        if (al_menu.size() > 0) {
            return al_menu.size();
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_photosfolder, parent, false);
            viewHolder.tv_foldern = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_folder);
            viewHolder.tv_foldersize = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_folder2);
            viewHolder.iv_image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_image);


            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.tv_foldern.setText(al_menu.get(position).getStr_folder());
        viewHolder.tv_foldersize.setText(al_menu.get(position).getAl_imagepath().size()+"");



        Glide.with(context).load("file://" + al_menu.get(position).getAl_imagepath().get(0))
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                .skipMemoryCache(true)
                .into(viewHolder.iv_image);


        return convertView;

    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tv_foldern, tv_foldersize;
        ImageView iv_image;


    }


}
```

Comment: you can set uri as tag on view and can get by tag onitemclick

Answer (score 0):

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int int_position, long l) {
            Model_images modelImage = (Model_images) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(int_position);
            Uri uri = modelImage.getAl_imagepath(); 
            //From here you can send uri to  next activity } });
        }
```

Or Use the below Method

```
public interface ImageClickListener{
    void onClickImage(String url);
}
```

Add Interface in your activity

```
public YourActivity implements ImageClickListener
```

Your Adapter Will look like this

Comment: Arbaz Rizvi I tried your suggestion but in the following line: Uri uri = modelImage.getAl_imagepath().get(l); I get this error: get (int) in ArrayList cannot be applied to (long)

Comment: Can you share your "Model_images" class

Comment: I just edited my post and add the "Model_images" class

Comment: You need two positions to get your image from array. Instead of using item click listener just create one interface and send result back to your activity/fragment